Numbering pages with periodicity when printing with CSS
I have an HTML file that needs to be printed, and I want each printed page to display a page number. However, instead of sequential numbering (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), I need the page numbers to repeat in a periodic sequence, for example, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.
Currently, I can implement sequential numbering using CSS like this:
@page {
  @top-center { content: counter(page); }
}

Is it possible to implement page numbering with a periodic sequence (such as 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3) using CSS or any other method?

I believe using css alone cannot handle such logic, but combine it with JavaScript and you might be able to accomplish this.
Try using the dummy code below as some sort of guidance:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Periodic Page Numbers</title>
    <style>
        @media print {
            .page-number {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                background: white;
            }
            .page {
                page-break-after: always;
                position: relative;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <!-- Your content for page 1 -->
        <p>Page 1 content...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <!-- Your content for page 2 -->
        <p>Page 2 content...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <!-- Your content for page 3 -->
        <p>Page 3 content...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <!-- More content for additional pages -->
        <p>Page 4 content...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Add more pages as needed -->
    
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('beforeprint', function() {
            const pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
            const periodicNumbers = [1, 2, 3];

            pages.forEach((page, index) => {
                let pageNumber = periodicNumbers[index % periodicNumbers.length];
                let footer = document.createElement('div');
                footer.className = 'page-number';
                footer.textContent = `Page ${pageNumber}`;
                page.appendChild(footer);
            });
        });

        window.addEventListener('afterprint', function() {
            document.querySelectorAll('.page-number').forEach(footer => footer.remove());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Hope that helps :)
